# How to prevent page refresh when using ng5-slider for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an ng5-slider which has a range from 0 - 1000 and is adjustable by the user.

When I adjust the slider at the bottom of the page, the page refreshes and pulls me to the top of the page.

I would like to prevent that from occurring. How do I do this ?

Here is my code:

page.component.html

```
          <div>
            <ng5-slider 
              [(value)]="minValue"
              [(highValue)]="maxValue" 
              (userChangeStart)="onUserChangeStart($event)"
              (userChangeEnd)="onUserChangeEnd($event)"
              [options]="options"
              (userChange)="onUserChange($event)">
            </ng5-slider>
          </div>
```

page.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.scss']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  logText = '';
  arr_price = [];
  minValue = 0;
  maxValue = 1000;
  options: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 1000
  };

  getChangeContextString(changeContext: ChangeContext): string {
    return `${changeContext.value} ${changeContext.highValue}`;
  }

  onUserChangeStart(changeContext: ChangeContext): void {
    this.logText = this.getChangeContextString(changeContext);
  }

  onUserChangeEnd(changeContext: ChangeContext): void {
    this.logText = this.getChangeContextString(changeContext);
    this.apply();
  }

  onUserChange(changeContext: ChangeContext): void {
    this.logText = this.getChangeContextString(changeContext);
    const value = this.logText;
    const value_arr = value.split(' ');
    this.arr_price = value_arr;
  }
}
```

I've tried to remove (userChangeStart) and (userChangeEnd) and the page did not reload which is what I want.

However, when I manually click the refresh button, the slider values reverted back to its original 0 --------------- 1000.

I am thinking that I have to implement userChangeStart and userChangeEnd for data to be persisted but if only I can somehow prevent page reload from within these handler functions...

Comment: 1. Can you reproduce in a stackblitz? 2. What's going on in apply()? 3. Does is still reload when you remove either userChangeStart or userChangeEnd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the bug by setting scrollPositionRestoration to disabled in the app routing module.

Initially it was set to enabled and thus any click event at the bottom of the page will bring the page to the top.

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled' })]
```